# How do I understand the intuition behind percentile point function?

Tags: probability, distributions, statistical-significance, beta-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution

I'm really trying very hard to understand the intuition behind percentile point function. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function), It is the inverse of cdf.

From the CDF, a point on its curve indicates the percentage of points less than or equal to that point. I hope this is the right understanding ?

For ppf to be inverse of cdf, the definition of a point on its curve would indicate the value of the variable with probability less than or equal to the probability at that point. Is it the right understanding ?

How would the definition change in context of beta distribution, specifically beta.ppf() ?

Comment: I have updated my answer adding an example that illustrates the discrete case. By the way, if you found my answer useful, please consider accepting/upvoting it.

Answer (score 4):

For a random variable $X$ with cumulative distribution function $F(x) = P(X\leq x)$, the usual definition of the quantile function is
$$
Q(p) = \inf\{x: F(x)\geq p\},\quad p\in(0,1)
.$$

Now if $X$ is absolutely continuous, then $F$ is continuous, monotone increasing and, in this case, $Q = F^{-1}$.

Now, in the continuous case, for any $p\in (0,1)$, the $p$th quantile, say $\xi_p = Q(p)$, can be seen as

> the particular value of the r.v. $X$ which leaves probability mass $p$
> on the left and probability mass $1-p$ on the right.

In other words, the $p$th quantile $\xi_p$ is s.t.

$$
p = P(X\leq \xi_{p}) = F(\xi_{p}).
$$

This interpretation holds for any distribution, the beta included.

For the discrete case consider the following example. Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with probability density function

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1/3 &\text{if } x=-1\\
1/6 &\text{if } x=0\\
1/2 &\text{if } x=1\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$

The distribution function is
$$F(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } x \in (-\infty, -1)\\
1/3 &\text{if }  x \in [-1, 0)\\
3/6 &\text{if }  x \in [0, 1)\\
1 &\text{if }  x \in [1, \infty)
\end{cases},
$$

and the quantile function is

$$
Q(p)=
\begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if } p\in(0,1/3]\\
0 & \text{if } p\in(1/3,3/6]\\
1 & \text{if } p\in(3/6,1)\\
\end{cases}.
$$

You can if you wish set $Q(0) = -\infty$ and $Q(1) = \infty$.